# Frequently updating data for Singapore

Tags: api, singapore

This sounds vague, because it can have many, many possible answers (I hope), but I will accept any of them.

Basically, I want to demo a product, which has an eInk display (plus WiFi and BlueTooth), to a company in Singapore:

[image]

To give them an idea of how it can be used to display their data, I would like to display some Singaporean data, maybe population, or similar.

The catch is that I want it to updated every second or so, displaying the temperature wouldn't be much good as it rarely varies.

I don't care what the data is, so is it on topic to ask for some Singaporean data which changes every second or so and has a gratis HTTP(S) API? I would like something to grab their attention and get them wondering how we can use [this (cheap) device](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000133121789.html).

Comment: In a demo, would be cool to have a temperature and/or CO2 sensor. That way you could exhale on the sensor or hold it in your hand and watch the display update

Comment: Not exactly Singapore related :-) but a good suggestion. Upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singapore offers an API for pollution levels (among [13 other real-time APIs](https://data.gov.sg/developer))

try it in their docs page: https://data.gov.sg/dataset/psi

or with curl

```
curl -X GET "https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/psi" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

or with the browser: https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/psi

---

(not sure if any of these 14 real-time APIs are actually enough *real-time*)

Comment: I doubt that pollution levels change quickly enough but have long thought that an air pollution device would sell well. I already saw that link to the real time APIs and thought of maybe something with taxis or parking spaces; those will certainly change on a per second basis. Upvote

Comment: The [Carpark Availability](https://data.gov.sg/dataset/carpark-availability) seems like it will change often enough to be useful

Comment: In the end, I had a lot of fun mapping the current locations of available taxis.