# Seeking any free, mappable real-time data which updates frequently (UK based is nice, but not necessary)

Tags: api, uk, real-time

I am looking for a free data feed (with HTTP(S) API) which I can use for various demos:

- something that I can map (both as markers and a heat-map)
- and chart the values
- real-time, and at least part of it should update often enough that someone looking at the page for 30 seconds (preferably less) will notice  change
- UK based is "nice to have" (London only is also acceptable), I also like Singapore (where the government have a lot of open data), but will accept anywhere
- a single datum suffices (with multiple values; e.g datum is train, values are all trains, multiple datums (data) would be different train companies)

Any ideas?

Comment: [My related question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16235/free-real-time-aviation-data-api] for UK aeroplane data and [my other related question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15329/free-source-of-ais-data-api/15354) for UK shipping.

Comment: Not UK< but I got [some good data for Singapore](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15859/frequently-updating-data-for-singapore)